# Growing crops on the Moon

Tags: plant-physiology, speculative

The short version of my question is this:

> It's some time in the future. I go into my back garden and focus my telescope on the Moon. The surface is virtually covered with giant greenhouses, growing food to support the cities that have sprung up there. The question is: *what plants are they growing in those greenhouses*?

Factors such as temperature, water, soil quality etc. can be controlled easily enough if you already have the ability to build sealed greenhouses in a vacuum. There are also a number of experiments on growing food in closed systems where air and water are recycled (the Biosphere 2 project being the best known). The low gravity can't be controlled, but there have been a number of experiments on plant growth in microgravity conducted on the international space station, so growing plants in Lunar gravity should be possible. There have also been some interesting results from growing plants in an Earth-based approximation to Lunar soil.

However, another important issue is the length of the Lunar day, which is 28 Earth days long, meaning that the Sun shines continuously for two Earth weeks, followed by two weeks of total darkness. I'm interested in what's known about how plants could adapt to this, but I haven't been able to find any research papers on the subject. Of course it would be possible to simulate an Earth day using artificial lighting, but the energy costs of doing this on a large scale would be rather high, so for economic reasons future Lunar farmers would likely want to keep it to a minimum.

So my first question is, has any research been done on the effect of extreme changes in day length on plant growth?

Secondly, is there any type of food plant that would be particularly likely to cope with such an environment (perhaps with some suitable genetic modifications)? For example, would normal crop plants such as cereals be able to build up enough sugar reserves in two weeks to survive the next two weeks in total darkness? If not, is there another type of plant that's more likely to be able to adapt to this? Or as an alternative strategy, is there any crop that grows fast enough that its shoots could be harvested after only two weeks of continuous sunlight? (Some individuals would have to be grown to maturity under artificial light in order to produce seeds, of course.)

Finally, I'd be grateful for pointers towards research on any other issues that I might have missed that are relevant to the problem of large-scale Lunar agriculture.

Comment: this question is quite long, perhaps you could make it clearer what you are trying to ask

Comment: @GriffinEvo are long questions considered bad here? If so that makes me sad. I think I've set out quite clearly what I'm asking in the final three paragraphs - could you please be more specific about what you found unclear?

Comment: There is no limit on length, I just feel that the key points you are trying to get to get a little lost and could be made to be more obvious, questions that are long or difficult to get to key point of are less likely to get good answers. So don't be sad :)

Comment: I suggest you rephrase your question to remove the reference to the moon. The obvious answer is that artificial light can be used and controlled so there is no reason why growing crops on the moon would be affected by its day/night cycle. Consider that if we have bases on the moon, we will already have lighting and the expense will be negligible compared to everything else necessary to make that possible. The question you are asking is how plants can/could adapt to different day/night cycles and it is a very interesting question but mentioning the moon distracts from it and confuses the issue.

Comment: @terdon I'm not talking about bases, I'm talking about large-scale agriculture. From basic thermodynamic considerations, providing a square kilometre of crops with full strength artificial daylight would require at least a square kilometre of solar panels, thus reducing the overall yield by 50%. Lunar agriculture might use some artificial light, but you'd really want to keep it to a minimum. I'll consider your suggestion, but I really am interested in the specific issues imposed by the Moon.

Comment: I agree with @terdon and think that the Q should be rephrased. Both "how plants cope with extreme day/night cycles" and "what plants that might be suitable for lunar greenhouses" are interesting questions, but at the moment your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @Nathaniel the specific issues imposed by the moon also include the details of lunar soil (different pH, lack of bacterial species and nutrients etc, see [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11538023)), the lack of atmosphere both as a source of necessary gasses and as a filter for UV. Since you seem to be exclusively interested in the effects of a different day/night question, I suggest you restrict your question to that.

Comment: @terdon I explained in the question that I'm aware of the relevant research pertaining to those issues (with the exception of the UV filtering, but that's trivially solved by coating the glass). However, there may be other issues that I haven't thought of. The question is about growing crops on the Moon, and these "I like your question but you should change it to a completely different question" comments are starting to bug me. I agree that a more generic question about adaptation to day length would also be interesting - please feel free to ask it yourself.

Comment: @Nathaniel I don't mean to bug you and you are, of course, welcome to leave the question as is. I am just pointing out that you are not making your point clear and that is reflected by the answer you have received and by the fact that you have already collected 3 close votes one each for unclear, too broad and primarily opinion based. Your call.

Comment: @fileunderwater if you can be specific about what you found unclear, I will gladly attempt to clarify it.

Comment: @terdon I expected better from this community, but if they choose to close it it's their loss. I'm an expert from another field with what I believe is a perfectly specific and well-defined (if somewhat speculative) question about biology, and if that's not welcome here then I guess this just isn't the site for me.

Comment: @Nathaniel don't take it personally! You may well believe that your question is clear but if people do not understand what you are asking, then it is obvious that others do not agree. Various people have already suggested ways of clarifying and there is clearly an interest in your question which I, personally, hope will stay here and get a good answer. You know how the SE sites work,this kind of back and forth is normal. You are also combining many questions in one which is bad form on all SE sites.

Comment: @terdon there is only one question. It is stated in a quotation block  at the top. The rest is clarification and background material - something which on most other stack exchange sites would be appreciated. I'm very happy to try and make it clearer, but if people keep just saying "it's unclear" without being specific about what they're having trouble with then there really isn't much I can do. Closing it would be perfectly reasonable if the question was against site policy, but it patently isn't, and the fact that the close votes are all for different reasons reflects this.

Comment: The question in the quote block is _what plants are they growing in those greenhouses?_ which cannot be answered, there are too many ways of dealing with the various problems that lunar cultivation raises. You could have GM crops, airtight greenhouses, a terraformed moon, artificial gravity, unicellular chemosynthesizing algae, solar mirrors, artificial light, soil transferred from Earth, modified lunar soil, unmodified lunar soil with modified plants, the list goes on. What seems clear to someone outside the field can be very complex to experts who know more of the underlying complexity.

Comment: @terdon yes, the quoted part can't be answered on its own. That's why the following section on background and clarification is necessary - but then people complained it was too long, so I can't win.

Comment: @terdon again, most of the things you mentioned are already covered in the question. People keep bringing them up even though I already covered them, and I don't understand why. But Basically all the options you mention are possibilities, with the exception of artificial gravity, which is physically impossible (trust me, I'm an expert and know more of the underlying complexity) and artificial lighting unless it's kept to a minimum, for reasons already discussed. The question is aimed at someone with the knowledge and imagination to weigh those options up and arrive at a solution.

Comment: I think I can re-write it to be clearer, but it will have to wait until I'm at my computer, either tomorrow or next week.

Comment: @Nathaniel One can be concise whilst being being clear. Your question has too many unknowns to give a specific answer and you seem to be looking for an overcomplicated answer. The basic answer is simple, humans would have to adapt (by modifying conditions on the moon to resemble those found on earth) the plants would likely have to do very little adaptation.

Comment: @GriffinEvo the question I have asked is difficult and requires a considerable amount if expertise to answer. That is quite a different thing from being too broad, and I didn't think it was against the rules. It must definitely *does* have a specific answer. I completely disagree that it can be asked any more concisely than its current form, and when I edit it for clarity it will necessarily get longer. I have explained many times why modifying the day length won't work, and if you ignore that then you are simply not addressing the question.

Comment: @Nathaniel you think that getting to the moon, providing sufficient water (a resource not found on the moon [in any large amounts at least so far]), building farms and filling them with artificial atmospheres (from gases not found on the moon), providing a nutrient rich soil substrate (again I believe this is not already on the moon), dealing with low gravity, and starting human colonies large enough to maintain and require these farms across the entire moon surface (not currently on the moon) are all feasible... but we can't manage to produce a light source?

Comment: @GriffinEvo those things are all one-off costs. Lighting requires a continuous supply of energy. Maybe there are other options (fission, fusion) but the most obvious source for that energy is solar panels, and as I've discussed at length, the issue then becomes one of land area. The idea of agriculture is to maximise yield from a given area of land, and if half that land is occupied by solar panels then only half can have crops growing on it, which seems quite inefficient.

Comment: @GriffinEvo that's not to say there can't be any light. The sunlight that reaches a shady spot on a cloudy day on Earth is probably less than 1% (maybe much less) of the total energy provided by the Sun, and supplying that level of artificial light becomes much more feasible. But you still have to use plants that can cope with a 28-day dusk-daylight cycle.

Comment: About availability of energy needed to artificially light the plants during lunar night, I wouldn't worry much: it's probably a lot smaller than the energy needed to keep greenhouses warm during that night.

Answer (score 1):

**Plants are adapted to the conditions we have here on earth**, therefore, for them to grow on the moon we would have to recreate the conditions found on earth (or at least find conditions that we can create and they can grow in). To do this we would need to replicate climate (temperature, air pressure, humidty etc.), provide (sun)light at the necessary intervals and intensity, provide water, air, and nutrients of the right composition, intervals and intensity. That is a simplified version...

**In reality there is great variation in how plants require these things**. Some cope with long dark periods better than others, some cope with drought better than others, some cope with chemical variation in the soil better than others so answering this question is hard. But generally growing plants on the moon will require the ability to recreate (to some degree depending on the sensitivity of the plant) the conditions a plant has evolved under on earth.

**Thus to answer your questions:**

Length of day can have strong effects on growth patterns, two weeks of darkness is likely to be a major upset for plants! Just transplanting plants of the same species from different latitudes can affect the growth patterns because of changes in length of day. Try putting some plants in darkness for two weeks and see what happens.

Plants all vary in their ability to meet the requirements of space growth. There will only be a short list of plants that could with "small" modifications to the moon's environment, the more we adapt (adding artificial light, watering, adding nutrients etc) the longer that list would become - the limitation is in our ability to adapt the moon.

See above for reasons why plants might struggle. Oh and we would need to consider the effects of reduced gravity too...

[Here's a little something from nasa](http://www.nasa.gov/audience/foreducators/spacelife/topics/plants/index.html#.UnjYE_mkpJk) about how plants are used in space vehicles. And [another on light and gravity](http://www.nasa.gov/audience/foreducators/topnav/materials/listbytype/How_Plants_Grow_in_Space.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I did mention in the question that I'm aware of research on most of these issues. I'm asking if there is any research specifically on the day length issue, and also about which specific types of plant are most likely to be able to adapt.

Comment: @Nathaniel I think if we get to the point where we can realistically inhabit the moon and modify it to grow some plants, then we should be able to get it to the point where most can grow. Whether it's wheat, corn, or oak trees, there will have to be some significant modifications made by us to the moon before we can grow any. Once we can grow one then small tweaks to the system will be needed to grow the others. Feels like its more how we could adapt the moon than how the plants can adapt. It's likely small simple things would be easiest for us to grow but crop plants would be most necessary

Comment: Sure - my thinking is that factors like water, soil quality, atmosphere etc. are easy enough to control if you already have the technology to build sealed greenhouses in a vacuum. Gravity can't be controlled at all, but if we can grow plants on the ISS then it should work on the Moon. That leaves the day length, which can only be changed using artificial lighting, which will need an expensive source of energy. So my guess is that the choice of which crop to grow would be mostly determined by its ability to cope with weeks of darkness.

Comment: @Nathaniel I can't find any research testing such long periods of light deprevation but my gut feeling is telling me not much would do well. These shade tolerant plants still need a few hours of sunlight per day http://www.motherearthnews.com/organic-gardening/shade-tolerant-vegetables-zm0z11zsto.aspx#axzz2jr6hxNjP

Comment: something like this might work... http://www.nytimes.com/1993/01/12/science/russians-to-test-space-mirror-as-giant-night-light-for-earth.html?pagewanted=all&src=pm